# CI(3) Login System troubleshooting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this CI(3) that I working on. Registration part works fine while Login just flashes to the same screen after submitting.

Controller:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
$template['homepage'] = '../../templates/vacations/users/login-logout';
$this->load->view('template_login',$template); }
public function validate_credentials() {
$this->load->model('membership_model');
$query = $this->membership_model->validate();
if ($query)  // If validated then {
$data = array(
'v_member_username' => $this->input->post('v_member_username'),
'is_logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this- load- library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
redirect('admin/dashboard');
} else {
$template['homepage'] = '../../templates/vacations/users/login-logout';
$this->load->view('template_login',$template);
}}
```

Model:

```
class Membership_model extends CI_Model {
public function validate() {
$this->db->where('v_member_username', $this->input->post('v_member_username'));
$this->db->where('v_member_password', md5($this->input->post('v_member_password')));
$query = $this->db->get('vbc_registered_members');
if($query->num_rows == 1) {
return true;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<?php echo form_open('login/validate_credentials', "class='login-form'"); ?>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="v_member_username" class="input-text input-large full-width" placeholder="Enter Your Email Or Username" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Enter Your Email Or Username'" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['v_member_username'])){ echo $_POST['v_member_username'];}?>" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="v_member_password" class="input-text input-large full-width" placeholder="Enter Your Password" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Enter Your Password'" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">remember my details
</label>
</div>
<div class="inline inline-second">
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>login/register">Sign Up Now!</a>
</div>
<div class="clear:both;"></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn-large full-width sky-blue1">LOGIN TO YOUR ACCOUNT</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Moreover validation doesn't work on login for when submitted.

SQL:

```
`v_member_first_name` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
`v_member_last_name` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
`v_member_username` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`v_member_password` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

Comment: print the query and check that is getting returned from db.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply Niranjan..
All it happens when I try to login with md5.. if I remove it, it goes smooth. I guess I am doing something wrong.